# Physics behind current direction in a transformer on HF

Tags: transformer, magnetic-flux

Let's consider the following schematics:

[image]

According to the model, the current in the secondary winding always flows in the opposite direction than in the primary anywhere in 1-30 MHz range:

[image]

Could you please explain, why the current phase happens to be opposite in the secondary winding, or give a reference to the article that explains it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Lentz Law - a part of the general induction law. You see those winding direction dots near the inductor symbols. If the current in a moment goes into the primary coil at the dot end it comes out of the dot end of the secondary. This way the induction resists magnetic flux changes inside the transformer.

Note that the induction (=induced electric field as a consequence of changing magnetic field) happens in magnetic field around the wires. Your coils are fully coupled, so they have 100% common magnetic field.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the answer I was looking for!